# controller_test: NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x98583f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I try to test the should_create_appointment block. Here is the code:
**appointments_controller_test.rb**

```
.....
test "should create appointment" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now

    assert_difference('Appointment.count') do
      post appointments_url, params: { appointment: [@heikoAppointment.attributes, @heikoInvitation.user_id, @heikoInvitation.message] }
    end

    assert_redirected_to appointment_url(Appointment.last)
  end
...
```

**controllers/appointments_controller.rb**

```
def appointment_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:shopper_id, :status, :appointed, :processed, :shopping_list_id, invitation_attributes: [:user_id, :message ])
end
```

However when I run the test, I get this error in should_create_appointment:

```
AppointmentsControllerTest#test_should_create_appointment:
NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x98583f0>
    app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:141:in `appointment_params'
    test/controllers/appointments_controller_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <class:AppointmentsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/appointments_controller_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:AppointmentsControllerTest>'
```

Does somebody know what went wrong? Here are the fixtures:

**appointments.yml**

```
appointment_heiko:
 user: user_heiko
 appointed: <%= Time.now + 2.weeks %>
 processed: <%= Time.now - 1.weeks %>
 shopping_list: shopping_list_lebensmittel
 shopper: user_shopper
 status: <%= Appointment.statuses[:finished] %>
```

**invitations.yml**

```
invitation_heiko:
 user: user_heiko
 shopping_list: shopping_list_drogerie
 appointment: appointment_heiko
 accepted: true
 responded: <%= Time.now - 3.weeks %>
 message: 'Gerne akzeptiere ich die Einladung'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're passing `params` to the `post` request in the test. In the params hash, there will be two keys `appointment` and `invitation_attributes` other than `action`, `controller` and form-specific entities like `authenticity token` and `encoding`.

When your test runs, `params.require(:appointment)` will return an array. `permit` is a method that works on `hashes`, and not `arrays`. This clearly says that `params[:appointment]` should be a `hash`.

```
post appointments_url, params: { appointment: @heikoAppointment.attributes, invitation_attributes: { user_id: @heikoInvitation.user_id, message: @heikoInvitation.message } }
```

To actually see what params get passed into, replace your `create` action with the following.

```
def create
  render text: appointment_params
end
```

Now, if you try to create a new entity by submitting the form, you'll find the params sent as plain text by the server. This should give an idea of what's goes through in the `params` hash.

Comment: thanks for explanation, it works fine! Do you also know how to test the delete-function? I use this:       delete appointment_url(@heikoAppointment)  but then the Error appears: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails